# Validating if file was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST

Tags: php

If i'm moving the file using **move_uploaded_file**, therefore checking to ensure that the file was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism, do i need to use **is_uploaded_file** when validating the uploaded file.

I'm reading the php's doc and it states that **move_uploaded_file** and **is_uploaded_file** both check if the file was uploaded via HTTP POST...

Am I correct or am I missing something? One or the other, but no need to do both, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using `move_uploaded_file`, you don't need to check `is_uploaded_file`

`is_uploaded_file` can be useful for example if you're uploading an image that will then be processed and returned to the user, without actually being saved anywhere permanant on the server, for example.